# create modal view with transparent background Swift

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, swift, ios8

I have what I thought would be a pretty easy thing to accomplish. Basically I have one view controller with some data, let's call it view controller A. When you click a button, I want a second view controller (B) to show up overlaying the first one. However, I don't want B to fully cover A. I want B to be smaller and to basically create a dark transparent background through which you can still see A.

I've tried this through storyboard a lot where I create a segue of type modal and then I played with the presentation options (form, sheet, etc...), but basically always what happens is that the B view controller simply flows up and covers all of A.

There are some guides to doing this in ios 7 and Objective-C, but I haven't been able to manage to translate those to Swift/ios 8 yet (also this is for iPhone).

I'm not sure if anyone has tried this yet in ios 8, but if someone could give me some hints as to how to accomplish this, that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following in prepareForSegue -

```
    toBePresentedVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    presentingViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext      
    presentingViewController.presentViewController(self, animated: true completion: nil)
```

You can try few alpha options with background color to get a transparent effect with some color.

Comment: sorry for the delay. This is basically what I ended up doing.

Comment: Could you tell me where we have add this code. weather in VieController A or B

Comment: Is this to be used in the prepareForSegue?